# Is it possible to filter out merged branches in git for-each-ref?

Tags: git

Basically I want something similar to `git branch -a --no-merged` but I'd also like to list tags and I don't need the spaces before or stuff like `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

Can I do this with for-each-ref or is it better to just strip the stuff I don't want from `git branch` then get the tags separately?

Comment: With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), you can check out the new `git for-each-ref --no-merged master refs/heads/` command. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988664/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git for-each-ref` and the similar `git show-ref` do not have the ability to decide whether one reference is an ancestor of another on its own, but you can always build a pipeline, e.g.:

```
uninteresting=master # or some other way to identify ones to discard
git for-each-ref |
while read sha1 reftype refname; do
    if git merge-base --is-ancestor $refname $uninteresting; then
        # $refname / $sha1 "is merged", or is exactly equal
        ... do whatever you like here ...
    else
        # there is no ancestry path from $uninteresting back to $refname
        ... do whatever else you like here ...
    fi
done
```

Note that `git merge-base --is-ancestor master master` is always true.  If you don't want "equal but name differs" considered to be "merged" (and does this depend on whether it's a branch or some other ref type?) you will need some extra code here, but I suspect you do want "equal means merged".

Answer (score 11):

Actually, starting with the upcoming git 2.7 (Q4 2015), [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), will support the `--no-merged` option, allowing for an easy filter of the merged branches

```
git for-each-ref --no-merged master refs/heads/
```

With the doc:

```
--no-merged [<object>]:
```

> Only list refs whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).

---

See [commit 4a71109](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a71109aa442ba1a7045d36f6b148113c95ffc48), [commit ee2bd06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2bd06b0f735a00ce0216ca1d3391b13722d987), [commit f266c91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f266c9163b34ec55e453d27e1ed246d67ee3ced0), [commit 9d306b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d306b5a6077f026291df3c4a5968eaf95a92417), [commit 7c32834](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c32834813bd6aee5ce5b2c4131d9f34249bc9e3), [commit 35257aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35257aa01203bae74f9fb856fb02c10c4b3836e6), [commit 5afcb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5afcb90560586765bf21fb09959a8b4497804639), ..., [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746) (07 Jul 2015), and [commit af83baf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af83bafa4867ba16368e58f36e8311e9591e68f4) (09 Jul 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9958dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9958dd8685a0a8b3d6ecdd07e35d8ecb22b304a7), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> Some features from "`git tag -l`" and "`git branch -l`" have been made
> available to "`git for-each-ref`" so that eventually the unified
> implementation can be shared across all three, in a follow-up
> series or two.

```
* kn/for-each-tag-branch:
  for-each-ref: add '--contains' option
  ref-filter: implement '--contains' option
  parse-options.h: add macros for '--contains' option
  parse-option: rename parse_opt_with_commit()
  for-each-ref: add '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: add parse_opt_merge_filter()
  for-each-ref: add '--points-at' option
  ref-filter: implement '--points-at' option
```

---

[user3265569](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265569/user3265569) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416370/is-it-possible-to-filter-out-merged-branches-in-git-for-each-ref/32988664?noredirect=1#comment113441776_32988664):

> I've added some formatting using your suggestion.
>
> ```
> git for-each-ref --no-merged master \
>   --format='%(committerdate:relative),%(authorname),%(refname:short)' \
>   --sort=committerdate \
> | column -t -s ','
> ```

Comment: I've added some formatting using your suggestion. `git for-each-ref --no-merged master --format='%(committerdate:relative),%(authorname),%(refname:short)' --sort=committerdate | column -t -s ','`

Comment: @user3265569 Nice! Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.