# Sourcetree: Find out if a branch is merged

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

How can I know if a branch (or commit) is merged in SourceTree?

When Using `gitk --all`, it will show for a commit (or branch) *foo* all other branches, where *foo* is already merged into.

To clarify what I mean a screenshot: **The encircled (red) area shows all the branches where the current commit is part of. Can this be displayed in SourceTree as well?**

[image: Screenshot of gitk]

Comment: So you know a command-line way of finding it, but want to find a way to do it in Sourcetree specifically? I don't think it has that feature.

Comment: Yes! (Well, gitk is actually the built-in git gui, but it seems inferior to sourcetree except in this aspect...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But maybe it is easier after all to not use SourceTree for that feature

You can use an **custom action** defined in SourceTree and listing those merged branches.
That is not as integrated as gitk, but at least, you don't have to switch tool.

First define an [custom action, using `$SHA` for getting the selected commit](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Using+Git+in+Custom+Actions):

[image: Custom action]

It should call a script in your `%PATH%` called `git-bm` (see [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34651664/6309))

```
#!/bin/sh
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/); do
  if [ "${branch}" != "$1" ]; then
    t=$(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --merged "${branch}" refs/heads/|grep -v "${branch}"|grep "$1")
    if [ "${t}" != "" ]; then
      echo "${branch}"
    else
      t=$(git branch --contains "$1" | grep "${branch}")
      if [ "${t}" != "" ]; then
        echo "${branch}"    
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

That will list all branches from which you can access the current SHA1 (which is to say "all branches in which the current branch has been merged")

(Note: the syntax `git for-each-ref --merged` has been introduced in git 2.7.0 only - 4th of January, 2016. See for instance "[Is it possible to filter out merged branches in `git for-each-ref`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32988664/6309)")

Then invoke it on the commit you want:

[image: invoke custom action]

And will get you list of branches it has been merged into:

[image: list]

It is a workaround, but at least you don't leave SourceTree.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found out that this does not work after all. I want to show all branches this branch is merged into, not the other way around. (For example, if I merge the current branch into master, with your solution it will not show "master" in the list). Gitk does this correctly...

Comment: @JanRüegg so something like (pseudo-syntax): `for each branches: (git branch --merged abranch|grep currentBranch)`

Comment: @JanRüegg I have edited the answer with a script which should list "all branches this branch is merged into". Can you test it? It works on my side.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thank you very much! I manage to get the script to run through sourcetree, but then I get many errors like this: "error: unknown option `merged'
usage: git for-each-ref [options] [<pattern>]
...". I'm still trying to figure out what's the problem...

Comment: @JanRüegg please make sure you have git 2.7.0 installed.

Comment: Actually, the script only seems to work for local branches, and not remote branches... any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @JanRüegg Because I used `refs/heads`: you need to do the same for `refs/remotes`

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent of running `gitk --all` in [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) would be to choose *All Branches* from the drop-down list in the upper left corner:

[image: View All Branches in SourceTree]

The graph shows which branches have been merged where, just like `gitk` does.

However, finding out *exactly* which branches have been merged in the current one – that is the branches whose tips are *reachable* from `HEAD` – is more easily done from the command line, as you can simply say:

```
git branch --merged
```

If you want, you can also include *remote branches* in the list by adding the `--all` option:

```
git branch --all --merged
```

Finding out which branches have *not* been merged in the current one is just as easy:

```
git branch --no-merged
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I clarified the question with a screenshot, to show which part of gitk I'd like to "find" in SourceTree. But maybe it is easier after all to not use sourcetree for that feature, as you described...

Comment: As mentioned in the comment for the other answer, this does not work, either! I want to know which branches the current branch has been merged into, not the other way around!