# How to run a script which can determine whether cmd.exe or gnu mingw shell is running

Tags: windows, git, shell, cmd, mingw

I want to write a script which runs some git commands on Windows 7 platform.

The users have git tools installed or at least MINGW - the minimalist GNU for Windows.

The trouble is that some users run from the MINGW32 shell and others from cmd.exe.

Example shell using MINGW32 shell:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

Example shell using cmd.exe

```
>echo %COMSPEC%
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

Is there any way I can determine the shell from my initial script and then possibly run a windows batch file or otherwise a unix script?

Or another idea is to assume user will use git bash and just check $SHELL is /bin/sh.  Is that easier?

Comment: related: [How to get the cwd in a shell-dependend format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37293650/321973)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick I used is to name your sh script `git-xxx`.
(Replace xxx by a sensible name). Start your script with `#!/bin/sh`.

That way, you can launch '`git xxx`' (`git`<kbd>space</kbd>`xxx`) from a git-bash or a CMD session: it will use the MINGW shell every time.

Make sure that `git-xxx` (no extension) is in your `%PATH%`.
And you `PATH` should also include `<path/to/git/bin>` and `<path/to/git/usr/bin>`. 
For instance:

```
C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\bin;C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\usr\bin;
```

That last path has more than 200 unix commands compiled for Windows.

Comment: I tried with script called git-abc.sh with #!/bin/sh topline and some git commands but if I run from cmd.exe I get: fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all.

Comment: @AngusComber not `git-xxx.sh`. `git-xxx` (no extension). You invoke that script by typing `git xxx` (`git` space `xxx`)