# How to get the cwd in a shell-dependend format?

Tags: python, windows, bash, msys, dirname

Since I'm using both Windows' `cmd.exe` and [msysgit](/questions/tagged/msysgit)'s `bash`, trying to access the Windows-path output by `os.getcwd()` is causing Python to attempt accessing a path starting with a drive letter and a colon, e.g. `C:\`, which `bash` correctly determines an invalid unix-path, which instead should start with `/c/` in this example. But how can I modify a Windows-path to become its [msys](/questions/tagged/msys)-equivalent [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the script is running within `bash`?

Comment: related: [How to run a script which can determine whether cmd.exe or gnu mingw shell is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34651196/321973)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly but should work unless you create an environment variable `SHELL=bash` for Windows:

```
def msysfy(dirname):
    import os
    try:
        shell = os.environ['SHELL']
    except KeyError:  # by default, cmd.exe has no SHELL variable
        shell = 'win'
    if os.path.basename(shell)=='bash' and dirname[1] == ':':
        return '/' + dirname[0].lower() + '/' + dirname[2:]
        # don't worry about the other backslashes, msys handles them
    else:
        return dirname
```