# How to check if all my branches are equal to master branch?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I would like to know if there is a command which can check if all my branches are equal to the master branch.

I have a Github repo and I have many branches and sometimes I forgot if I did a "git rebase" on a given branch. For now it's okay, but later I will add many branches and it's boring to check each branch.

If someone has the solution, thanks :)
[The Github repo](https://github.com/luctst/Flexbox-Tips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally, you can use [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to compare your branch with master: if the result if master HEAD, that means your branch is equals to or rebased onto `master`.

You can see an example applied to all branches in "[Is it possible to filter out merged branches in git for-each-ref?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416558/6309)"

---

On GitHub, you can [compare branches](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparing-branches), but that would have to be done branch by branch.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, `git branch --no-merged HEAD` (given you're currently on master) might be what you're looking for:

from the git-branch manpage:

> --no-merged [< commit >]
>             Only list branches whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified). Implies --list, incompatible with --merged.

Otherwise you can just loop over all branches output by `git branch` and do a `git diff` agains master for each one